# What's the best way to add a model to an app in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I was asked to add a new categorization to an existing model in Rails. My first model, let's say posts need to get a many-to-many relationship to a new model Interest, in which certain areas of interest are stored. Each post can have 0 to many of these interests. Also, on go live these interests are already determined as a fixed list of 10 interests.

What's the best way to create the new model and pre populate the table with the 10 fixed areas of interest?

I was thinking of using a seed to populate the database, but I'm not really experienced with that. Is that the right way to go, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your application is running in a live production environment, it would be better to create the table and build the default associations with a migration.  Seeding the database is something that should only happen when the database is created, otherwise duplicate data may be introduced.

```
class CreateInterests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def migrate(direction)
    super

    if direction == :up
      ['Iterest 1', 'Interest 2', ..., 'Interest N'].each do |name|
        Interest.create(name: name)
      end

      interests = Interest.all

      Post.all.each do |post|
        post.interests << interests
      end
    end
  end

  def change
    create_table :interests do |t|
      t.integer :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :interests_posts, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :interest_id
      t.integer :post_id
    end

    add_index :interests_posts, [:interest_id, :post_id]
  end
end
```

Comment: that's assuming that ALL posts will belong to ALL categories. I doubt that's the initial state the OP wants.

Comment: @steveTurczyn The way I interpreted the question was to create an Interests model, create a HABTM join table between Interests-Posts, create a default set of Interests and associate them with the Posts.

Comment: I agree that OP wants HABTM but if all posts have all interests, what's the point of the feature?  He will presumably want to associate posts with interests on a post by post basis after he's created the new model(s) and the capabilities.

Comment: Not sure what your getting at.  My answer contains everything OP needs to set it up. Your answer doesn't even address the HABTM aspect.  If OP doesn't want all posts to have all interests by default, then he can remove that block.

Comment: No, no, it's a good answer, just saying that there doesn't appear to be any business reason to automatically assign all categories to all posts.

Comment: Thanks guys, didnt think about using the migration file to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a seed, but for such a small number of initial Interest objects I'd just do it in the migration.

Create the Interest model `app/models/interest.rb` first, then generate the migration and edit it to create the rows when you do `rake db:migrate`

```
class CreateInterests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :interests do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamp
    end
    Interest.create(name: "Animals")
    Interest.create(name: "Flowers")
    Interest.create(name: "Dinosaurs")
    # add seven more interests...
  end

  def down
    drop_table :interests
  end
end
```